# Cannot destructure property `name` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: node.js, typescript, back-end

por algum motivo o meu req.body está retornando undefined, mesmo com os middlewares corretos.

Controller

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import db from '../database/connection';

class ClassesController {
  public async store(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    try {
      const { name, avatar, whatsapp, bio } = req.body;

      await db('users').insert({
        name,
        avatar,
        whatsapp,
        bio,
      });

      return res.json({ msg: 'Sent' });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }
  }
}

export default new ClassesController();
```

ClassesRoutes

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import ClassesController from '../controller/ClassesController';

const routes = Router();

routes.post('/classes', ClassesController.store);

export default routes;
```

App

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import express from 'express';

import ClassesRoutes from './routes/ClassesRoutes';

class App {
  app: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();

    this.routes();
    this.middlewares();
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  }

  routes() {
    this.app.use(ClassesRoutes);
  }
}

export default new App().app;
```

Server

```
import App from './app';

const port = process.env.APP_PORT;
App.listen(port, () => console.log(`Conectado em http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Erro em si
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o motivo disso estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não use classes se você não precisa delas, são objetos complexos e não devem ser usadas inutilmente, tudo o que você escreveu em para a sua `App` poderia ser reduzido em:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(ClassesRoutes);
```

O mesmo vale para o seu `ClassesController`, você poderia simplesmente exportar um objeto com dentro os métodos que você precisa, de qualquer maneira a possível causa para o teu problema:

```
this.routes();
this.middlewares();
```

Depois de ter criado a tua app, você primeiro definiu as `routes` e só então os `middlewares`, a sua aplicação irá montar a pilha de "handlers" por ordem de chamada, ou seja você definiu o handler para a solicitação antes mesmo de ter feito o `parsing` do corpo da mesma, o que significa que ele não existe par ao seu controller, simplesmente invertendo deve resolver o teu problema:

```
this.middlewares();
this.routes();
```